# AVAudioPlayer prepareToPlay callback in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer

Is it possible to know when an `AVAudioPlayer` is ready after a call to `prepareToPlay`?

If not, is there any other class that provides this functionality?

I would like to implement something like this:

```
- (void) prepare {
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    // Update UI to indicate that the audio is being prepared
}

- (void) onAudioReady {
    // Update UI to indicate that the audio is ready
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this class that can help to initialize the audio and then play it instantly in your onAudioReady method.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager

with reference to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10417762/1474080

OR

you can check for the BOOL result from [audioPlayer prepareToPlay] to see if the audio hardware has been initialised according to the documentation. If the result is YES, you could generate some UI for user to see.

> prepareToPlay 
>   Prepares the audio player for playback by preloading its buffers.
>
> - (BOOL)prepareToPlay Return Value Returns YES on success, or NO on failure.
>
> Discussion Calling this method preloads buffers and acquires the audio
>   hardware needed for playback, which minimizes the lag between calling
>   the play method and the start of sound output.
>
> Calling the stop method, or allowing a sound to finish playing, undoes
>   this setup.